# How do I grant 777 (rw) permission in shared windows hosting

Tags: wordpress, shared-hosting, plugin, plesk

I have a windows shared hosting on which I have deployed my wordpress [blog](http://blog.subhendu.info/index.php). Now to icrese my page speed I am trying to cached few resources using [W3C Total Cache](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/w3-total-cache/)

While trying to activate the plugin I am getting the following error:

> E:\inetpub\vhosts\subhendu.info\httpdocs\blog/wp-content/dbcache could not be created, please run following command:
>   chmod 777 E:\inetpub\vhosts\subhendu.info\httpdocs\blog/wp-content
>   then Retry

I tried creating few directories using FTP but realized it wont be of any use as caching files also can not be placed dynamically.

I tried changing the chmod to 777 using FileZilla but getting the error:
***500 'SITE CHMOD 777 wp-content': command not understood*** mostly because this is a windows hosting. Again I do not have to shell access to my server , I have to everything using FTP.

If there is no other way  and I have to ask my hosting provider for support what shall I ask him? Does he need to grant RW permisiion to any specific users?

Comment: I deleted my other answer because I hadn't read your question carefully. Does your shared hosting have a control panel? Most control panels allow you to change file permissions.

Comment: @paulmorriss, Yes they have Parallels Plesk Panel

Comment: @paulmorriss,Thanks . I am able to change the directory settings using ControlPanel

Comment: I turned it into an answer in case it's helpful to other people.

Comment: @paulmorriss,If you can add the complete details to your answer for changing permission using Plesk :Websites & Domains > File Manager > Folder Name > Click on The Lock Symbol . I have also retagged my question to Plesk

Comment: Thanks for the detail. Hopefully its a widely useful answer now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most shared hosting providers have a control panel. Most control panels allow you to change file permissions through some sort of file manager. Windows uses a different way of doing permissions to Unix servers, so you may need to give read/write permission to a user called IUSR_*machinename* for Wordpress to work properly.

For Plesk it's: Websites & Domains > File Manager > Folder Name > Click on The Lock Symbol